# Mongodb: Dumping a database A and then restoring it as database B results in database B with correct but empty collections

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodump, mongorestore

I am trying to duplicate a database called `database_A` in the same cluster.
The result should be a new database called `database_B` with the exact same data.

For this, I am following the instructions mentioned in MongoDb Atlas/command line tools:
[image]

1/ I have run the dump command:

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://ahmed:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/database_A
```

2/ This created a folder `dumb/database_A` containing the `database_A` data
3/ Now, I am trying to create `database_B`containing the `database_A` data
4/ In order to do this, I changed the name of the database folder `dump/database_A` to `dump/database_B`
5/ Then I tried to restore `dump/database_B` by running this command:

```
mongorestore --uri mongodb+srv://ahmed:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/database_B
```

`database_B` got successfully created with the same collections as `database_A`.
However, for some reason, all the collections are empty.
Any idea why?

---

**NOTE:** This error occured when I run the dump command:
[image]
So maybe, it has something to do with the face that the collections are empty.

Comment: You need to use `mongorestore` for restoring.

Comment: You can try this procedure to make a copy of the database: [mongodump - Copy/Clone a Database](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#copy-clone-a-database).

Comment: @prasad_ I did use restore. I wrote dump by mistake in the 5th step. The link you mentioned explains how to do it in a local instance.

Comment: You can supply your cluster's connection string using appropriate options to the commands.

Comment: I tried this: "mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://ahmed:password@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net --archive="mongodump-test-db" --db=test_db " but I get this error: "illegal argument combination: cannot specify --db and --uri"